# dbms_job not running at sqlplus shell

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I'm trying to run dbms_job at sqlplus shell but failed.
In toad i managed to run this at "Editor"->"Execute statement"

```
exec dbms_job.isubmit(1234, 'TEST;',SYSDATE,INTERVAL => 'SYSDATE+(2/24/60)');
/
```

successfully

But when i run

```
    [abc]$ sqlplus user/password @compile1.sql

    compile1.sql's content    
    spool compile.log;
    @try.sql
    spool off;
```

try.sql's content

```
exec dbms_job.isubmit(1234, 'TEST;',SYSDATE,INTERVAL => 'SYSDATE+(2/24/60)');
```

after runnning compile1.sql, this appears

```
[abc]$ sqlplus ESERV/ESERV @compile1.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Tue Jan 28 13:46:11 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

and it stucked there forever.
I did try to include `begin ... end`;

but still it doesn't succeed , kindly advise if you have any idea, thanks !

regards,
Tan

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your try.sql's content like this :

```
exec dbms_job.isubmit(1234, 'TEST;',SYSDATE,INTERVAL => 'SYSDATE+(2/24/60)');
/

EXIT;
```

Comment: I found out the solution for this issue. My try.sql is missing '/' at the last line which caused the hang issue.

Comment: the hang issue happens again even though i've added the '/' at last line of the sql script. nohup does not really help in this scenario.

Comment: hi Rida,could you simulate this at your end ? i'm sure you'll hit the same problem too...